# Debian Buster LXDE: Weather Plugin

Tags: debian, lxde, plugin

I'm using Debian Buster LXDE and tried some new location in the Weather Plugin. Here are some interesting search results (`| City  | State | Country |`):

- **Paris**

  ```
  | Paris | Maine | United States of America |
  ```
- **Buenos Aires**

  ```
  | Buenos Aires | Arizona | United States of America |  
  | Buenos Aires | Cauca   | Colombia                 |
  ```
- **Amsterdam**

  ```
  |           |            | France                   |  
  | Amsterdam | New York   | United States of America |  
  | Amsterdam | California | United States of America |  
  | Amsterdam | New Jersey | United States of America |
  ```
- ... etc ...

So, basically the Weather Plugin missed almost all location I've tried.

**QUESTION**

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You aren't putting in enough data, this isn't a magic box, put in the right locations and it will probably work fine. Or better yet, just delete this question since it's not asking anything, it's just stating the obvious, you need to give more data for locations, all weather apps are that way to dome degree or other.

Comment: @Lizardx Just tried putting more data. Still, very poor results. Ex: `Location 'Amsterdam, Netherlands' not found!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me only the
"01001, Ukraine"
works.

Found https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxpanel/+bug/1539930 also for a suggestion how to enter a location via config file.

Comment: As someone commented in this bug report: "Manually editing the panels config file with my information does not effect the weather plugin". The same happened to me.

Comment: Based on this bug report, seems that this is a known issue since beginning of 2016. And at the end of 2016 there was already a fix for it. I'm wondering why this fix is not available yet to Debian.